# Using Cookies in Yew

Tags: cookies, rust, yew

I'm building a Rust + Yew app rendered on the client side. After looking for some time in the docs, I couldn't found the proper way to handle cookies. Does anybody knows how to do it?

I want to set an auth token in the cookies.

Comment: I failed using cookies as well. So, I switched to `LocalStorage` using `gloo-storage` which I found more handy to use. https://docs.rs/gloo-storage/latest/gloo_storage/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [wasm-cookies](https://docs.rs/wasm-cookies/latest/wasm_cookies/) if you just want to handle cookies on the client side. The library comes with its pitfals but after struggling a bit in the beginning I think it is ok to use.

I personally find that [gloo-storage](https://crates.io/crates/gloo-storage) provides a much more intuitive way to handle user information on the client side if that is whay you are aiming for and if you are ok with using local/session storage and not cookie storage (which come all with its drawbacks and benefits).

If you want to use cookies to handle user sessions, authentication, etc. and if you use `actix` for your backend I found [actix-session](https://docs.rs/actix-session/latest/actix_session/) to be easy to use. They provide a copy-paste example which works out of the box and should give you a quick start with authentication.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, although it might require some slight modification ...

```rs
use web_sys::HtmlDocument;
use wasm_bindgen::JsCast;

pub fn set_cookie(name: &str, value: &str, expires: bool, path: &str) {
    let cookie = format!("{}={}; expires={}; path={}", name, value, expires, path);
    gloo::console::log!("cookie: {}", &cookie);
    let document = gloo::utils::document().unchecked_into::<HtmlDocument>();
    match  document.set_cookie(cookie.as_str()){
        Ok(_) => gloo::console::log!("setting cookie ...."),
        Err(err) => gloo::console::error!("error setting cookie:{}", err)
    }
}
```